# How to sort ConcurrentBag<Tuple<string,int,decimal>>() by Item3 in c#?

Tags: c#

I have a `ConcurrentBag<Tuple<string,int,decimal,string>> pricelist` and want to sort it by `pricelist.Item3`

I previously just had a `List<Tuple<string,int,decimal,sting>> priceList` and sorted it with:

`priceList.Sort((x, y) => x.Item3.CompareTo(y.Item3));`

due to multithreading processing i exchanged it with a ConcurrentBag but I dont know how to sort the concurrent bag.

for this reason, please help me how I can sort `priceList` by `Item3`

this is my current pseudo Code:

```
    ConcurrentBag<(string intemID, int amount, decimal price, string seller)> temporaryPriceList = new ConcurrentBag<(string, int, decimal, string)>();
    Parallel.ForEach(cardProductIDs, (productID) =>
    {
        int indexCondition = GlobalVar.cardConditions.IndexOf(card.condition);
        foreach (var price in task.GetProductSellers(int.Parse(productID), minUserScore, idLanguage, indexCondition))
        {
            temporaryPriceList.Add(price);
        }
    });
    temporaryPriceList.OrderBy(element.price);
```

this is my previous, working code:

```
    List<Tuple<string, int, decimal, string>> temporaryPriceList = new List<Tuple<string, int, decimal, string>>();
    // add sellers for productcategory
    foreach (string productID in cardProductIDs)
    {
        int indexCondition = GlobalVar.cardConditions.IndexOf(card.Item3);
        temporaryPriceList.AddRange(GetProductSellers(int.Parse(productID), minUserScore, idLanguage, indexCondition));
    }
    // sort
    temporaryPriceList.Sort((x, y) => x.Item3.CompareTo(y.Item3));
    // Process with the cheapest sellers
```

Comment: Stack is LIFO ordering collection. Sorting stack violates its purpose - it won't be a stack anymore. Why do you want to sort it? Maybe, you want to sort its projection?

Comment: The primary reason I sorted the list was because it was the easiest way to get the cheapest element `price[0]`. Otherwhise I had to iterate over the list manually in some different way to obtain the cheapest price. Also later it can be easier and faster when i for example can just cut the expensivest 80% awayfrom further processing. But maybe there are two drifferent ways to obtain the x cheapest elements and the cheapest one.

Comment: `Tuple<string, int, decimal, string>` screams "create a class" in my opinion. If you want a thread-safe collection, then `ConcurrentBag` seems like a better option. You can simply project it with `OrderBy`.

Comment: how would you do an `addRange` best with ConcurrentBag @DanWilson

Comment: I would just call `Add()` in a loop. That's essentially what `AddRange()` does.

Comment: You could do something like `cardProductIds.AsParallel().SelectMany(p => task.GetProductSellers(…)).OrderBy(x = x.Item3).ToList()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort your data this way:

```
temporaryPriceList.ToArray()
.OrderBy(v=>v.Item3)
.ToArray()
```

Comment: I ended up using `temporaryPriceList.OrderBy(v=>v.Item3)`